# Validating Information Before Moving to Next View in Swift

Tags: mysql, swift, synchronous

I have an application where I need to validate some information(zip code) from a database before I allow my iOS application to proceed to the next view. I used the zip code project to import a DB Table will all valid US Zip codes, and I want to have the zip code the inputed by the user validated before I allow them to proceed.  If the zip code isn't valid, I hold them up at the current view and display an alert.  I have a class to validate the zip code, but the zip code isn't being validated until after the next view is loaded.  I've been leaning towards using a completion handler, but I'm not exactly sure if that's my best/only option.  Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
The following is the whole class for retrieve the data

```
protocol ZipCodeLocationProtocol: class {
    func zipCodeLocationDownloaded(zipLocation: Location)
} 

class RetrieveZipCodeLocation: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

// MARK: Properties
weak var delegate: ZipCodeLocationProtocol!
var data: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()


let urlPath: String = "xxxx"

func downloadZipCodeLocation(zipcode: Int)  {

        let path = self.urlPath + "?zipcode=\(zipcode)"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: path)!
        var session: NSURLSession!
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url)

        task.resume()


}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {

    self.data.appendData(data)

}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {

    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download data")
    }else {
        print("Data downloaded")
        self.parseJSON()
    }

}

func parseJSON() {
        var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        var location = Location(title: "TITLE", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0))


        do {
            jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:[]) as! NSMutableArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)

        }

        var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()

        for(var i = 0; i < jsonResult.count; i++) {

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let point = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (jsonElement["LATITUDE"] as! NSString).doubleValue, longitude: (jsonElement["LONGITUDE"] as! NSString).doubleValue)
            // Get Information
            location = Location(title: "TITLE", coordinate: point)



            self.delegate.zipCodeLocationDownloaded(location)
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you show some code where you are calling the validation function?

Comment: I've added the code to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that a button triggers the segue to the next view. I'm also going to assume that the button is hooked up to a function for target-action. I'm also going to assume that you have the code to get the zip codes, otherwise you'll have to ask a separate question for that.

Assumptions aside, you need to present a `UIAlertController` **instead** of going to the next view controller when tapping the button. In order to do that:

```
func buttonAction() {

    if verifyZipCode() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hold Up", message: "That zip code is invalid.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let fixIt = UIAlertAction(title: "Fix It!", style: .Default, handler: nil) // handler could also contain code to make text field red or something interesting

        alert.addAction(fixIt)

        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        // existing segue code
    }

}

func verifyZipCode() -> Bool {
    // Take text field text and verify zip code
}
```

Comment: All of your assumptions are correct.  I understand the logic behind all of that.  The problem is that I'm using a delegate to update the information, and the rest of the code continues to execute before receiving that response.  I currently just placed a time delay so I'd have time to retrieve the information from the server.

Comment: @ChrisDavis You can show a loading symbol and wait to check the zip codes, then execute this code.

Comment: I'm somewhat unfamiliar with using the UIActivityIndicatorView, but I have added it to my view.  Would I want to start animating it before I called my checkZipCode func and then stop animating it inside the checkZipCode func after the zip code is validated?

Comment: Was able to get it working with the activity indicator, Thanks!